# I can't execute npm scripts in node why is this happening and how can i solve it

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I need help fixing this problem I hope this can help and I tried running other commands in my terminal but it did not work 15.5.1

My version of node is the latest one.

- The code says three things

  - Commmand failed at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
  - verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run-script" "dev"
  - error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c concurrently "nodemon dist/server.js" tsc -w

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'run-script',
0 verbose cli   'dev'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.3.0
2 info using node@v15.5.1
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
8 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\louis\Desktop\web-projects\natours\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\louis\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\louis\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 8ms
19 verbose npm-session 09d944228c5c6035
20 timing npm:load Completed in 18ms
21 timing command:run-script Completed in 464ms
22 verbose stack Error: command failed
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1063:16)
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:295:5)
23 verbose pkgid natours@1.0.0
24 verbose cwd C:\Users\louis\Desktop\web-projects\natours
25 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
26 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run-script" "dev"
27 verbose node v15.5.1
28 verbose npm  v7.3.0
29 error code 1
30 error path C:\Users\louis\Desktop\web-projects\natours
31 error command failed
32 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c concurrently "nodemon dist/server.js" tsc -w
33 verbose exit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and just by running the commands with the silent flag on, seems to be solving the problem. In my case I was getting the same error when i was running `npm install`. Running:
`npm install --silent`
 worked. From the flag explanation on npmjs docs `--silent` seems to just to be hiding the messages from the terminal, but without the silent flag up, I was not able to see my node_modules installed. Now the application seems to be working fine.

Comment: --silent suppresses the error and not eliminate/solve it.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

If you use TailwindCSS ^2.0, then make sure that your **package.json** file contains **vue-template-compiler**. This was causing all the issues to me...

Example/working package.json file

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.4",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.16.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "^3.2.11",
    "postcss": "^8.2.4",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  }
```

### Previous comment

1. Remove webpack-cli from package.json (manually)
2. Uninstall all npm modules `npm uninstall *`
3. Reinstall them (without webpack-cli). *Note: npm will ask you if you want webpack-cli to be installed, so just click yes)* `npm install`
4. It will work fine at this point (for 1 time)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't add "Me too" as answers as it doesn't provide any information. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it. If you're interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem.
It seemed to be caused by an outdated node version, which was fixed by running:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```